# Filling a combo box with data from MySQL database

Tags: java

I used NetBeans editor for Java programming. I do not know what is wrong with the following code that fills a combo box with data from MySQL database:

```
    private void fillComboBox(ArrayList<Product> a) {
    filling = true;
    productComboBox.removeAllItems();
    for (Product p : a) {
        productComboBox.addItem(p);
    }
    filling = false;
}
```

When the  the combo box is filled with the ID column of the table, the data from the remaining columns are displayed in their respective textfields. It works fine, but when I compiled it, I was asked to recompile with Xlint. I did recompiled the code and an arrow was pointing to the for (Product p : a);
I am not always comfortable with the Xlint message.
How do I correct  whatever is causing the problem?

Comment: How is `productComboBox` declared? Is it `JComboBox<Product>`?

Comment: What error did you get? NullPointerException? Something else? Is there an error or a warning in netbeans?